# Why aren't electrons composite particles like protons are?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, nuclear-physics, standard-model, protons

I asked this question previously, but it was closed. I would like to try to explain what I am asking in a better manner.

Protons and electrons are opposite in charge: one is positive, and the other is negative. I am not questioning the reasoning behind this. I am questioning why they differ so greatly in mass and composition. The proton is a composite particle and is more massive, while the electron is an elementary particle and is less massive. There are two alternative scenarios: one in which the proton is more like the electron (less massive and elementary), and where the electron is more like the proton (more massive and composite). If the proton was more like the electron, it would make sense that the strong interaction would no longer affect them, so matter would fly apart. But if electrons were more like protons, there wouldn't be too much of a difference. Matter would remain stable. So, why aren't electrons composite particles like protons are?

Comment: 'why' is a very hard question to answer, if not impossible to answer. It just is - we see something that looks fundamental with negative (in our chosen convention) charge, we call it an 'electron'. We also see some composite particle with positive charge, essentially stable, three valence quarks - we call it a proton. What answer are you looking for?

Comment: why should they be the same?

Comment: To make us what we are.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! :) This good question is easier to answer, when we know your academic background or school level.

Comment: Why is a unicycle different from a tricycle?

Comment: @StefanBischof This is not a "good question." First, it is impossible to answer. Second it is compound.

Comment: Funny that OP mentions 'obvious difference in charges', since the actual open problem is the unexplained fact that they have the exact same charge (with only a difference in sign).

Answer (score 1):

As already remarked in a comment, "why" questions are difficult to answer. In fact, they only make sense within a specific theoretical framework.

If you accept the standard model (SM) of particle physics as your fundamental theoretical framework, you encounter the following situation: The fundamental spin 1/2 fields (of the first generation) are the electron, neutrino, up-quark and down-quark fields. The electron and the neutrino fields "feel" the electromagnetic and weak interactions (mediated by the photon, $W$ and $Z^0$ fields), whereas the $u$ and $d$ fields "feel" in addition also the strong interaction (mediated by the gluon field).

The electron can exist as a free particle (a particle you can register in a detector) as an "excitation" of the electron field. This is quite in contrast to the $u$ and $d$ fields. Because of "colour confinement" (a characteristic property of strong interactions described by quantum chromodynamics), there are no corresponding free particles. Only "colourless" bound states (hadrons) can exist as free particles.

"What is the lightest spin $1/2$ hadron in the SM?" is now a reasonable question. The answer is, it is a colour-neutral $u u d$ bound state with electromagnetic charge $2/3+2/3-1/3 =+1$ called "proton" (the $u$ field has electromagnetic charge $2/3$ and the $d$ field has electromagnetic charge $-1/3$). The spin $1/2$ colour-neutral $udd$ bound state with total electromagnetic charge $2/3-1/3-1/3=0$ is a bit heavier and we call it "neutron".

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the quantum numbers and the [standard model of elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)? To my knowledge the "why" still has no answer. You are asking about these elementary particles, because you observe them daily. I can't answer why we the matter around us is not all consisting of anti-up and charm quarks. The standard model predicts, which 3 (5) quarks are "able to exist" at certain energies. Further life benefits not to be annihilated by co-existence with anti-particles.

It is a fundamental observation, that two classes of particles exist. You mentioned particles which are all fermions with exception of the photon beeing a boson.

Answer (score -1):

Just a note. What if the electron and the proton were the same?

There is a particle that is the same as the electron except for the charge. And it has the same electric charge as the proton. It is the positron, the anti-particle of the electron.
Both particles have an electric charge and a magnetic moment. Only, when brought together, they annihilate to form photons, i.e. electro-magnetic radiation. Thus, no stable matter can exist.

In this respect, it should not be surprising to live in a world with different properties of particles of different charges.